# How can I fix Object reference not set to an instance of an object in my C# code

Tags: c#

```
private void label16_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panelSummary.Show();
    StockInfo temp = Game.getStockByLabelName(label16.Text);
   // StockComp.Text = "Stock Company = " + temp.getStockName();// I got errors in this line
    lbDispStockPrice.Text = "Stock price = " + temp.getPrice();
    lbDispStock.Text = "Stock category = " + temp.getCategory();
    owner.Text = "Property Of " + temp.getBuyer();
}
```

Comment: Well presumably `getStockByLabelName` has returned null... you need to find out why.

Comment: Why do you have a "c" tag on here when this is not C, and what line is throwing the error? One of the objects you are referencing (panelSummary, Game, temp, etc.) is null. Did you step through the debugger and see which one?

Comment: I second the suggestion to fire up a debugger to see which variable in the statement that errors out is `null`.

Answer (score 1):

To "stop the exception" on the line you indicated check for `null` returned by `GetStockByLabelName`

```
StockInfo temp = Game.getStockByLabelName(label16.Text);

if(temp != null)
{
     StockComp.Text = "Stock Company = " + temp.getStockName();//if temp is null then EX
     //...
}
else
       //do whatever is appropriate for the situation where StockInfo is null
```

StockComp.Text could be causing the error.  I assume this is a `TextBox` created in the designer so unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that each of these references is not `null`:

```
panelSummary
temp 
lbDispStockPrice
lbDispStock
owner
```

My guess would be `temp` since the others seem to be visual components, which would mean `Game.getStockByLabelName` is returning `null` when passed the value in `label16.Text`.

This is where the debugger comes in handy...